# Obtengo error Password can't be blank ruby on rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs-2.0

Estoy usando Rails y angular 2 para mi app, en mi api rails tengo agregada la

```
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
```

mi tabla de base de datos tiene `password_digest: string` y mi modelo `has_secure_password`.

Cuando envió mi formulario obtengo error

> Password can't be blank

**Rails controller**:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

    def create 
        @user = User.new(user_params)

        if @user.save 
            session[:user_id] = @user.id 
            render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user
        else 
            render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
        end 
    end

    private
    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password)
    end
end
```

**Angular2**:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.Form = this.fb.group({
        first_name: this.fb.control(null, Validators.required),
        last_name: this.fb.control(null, Validators.required),
        email: this.fb.control(null, Validators.required),
        password: this.fb.control(null, Validators.required)
    });
}
```

Comment: Puedes checar en los modelos que tienes si tienes algun "validates presence of" por parte de ruby